# How to change the user registration form in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I'm new to Joomla and I want to change the user registration form style (in Joomla 2.5).

The problem is I didn't find any css file to change the style. [This is my page](http://www.import-produit-allemand.com/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/users-component/registration-form). What ways are there?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a template override for the registration view. For more information on that, have a look at the following link:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Once done, you can start editing the layout and styling so that it won't get overridden in any possible updates